How do I add react webpage on git
I have no idea how to add react app to git pages. (I want it in display like git pages.)
I tried looking through tutorials but I meet error after error
also if I import it like how I did to html files it would show a page about "Getting Started with Create React App"

Look into this might help: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Hi there. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.
